# Why are large files in my Docker image getting pushed each time even when no changes have been made to them?

Tags: docker

I have a docker image that I'm building with a Dockerfile.

The dockerfile contains some COPY statements.  On one of them is a large file of around 120MB.

It's written in the form COPY myfile /data/

When I do a docker push to a remote registry it takes a very long time every time.  Despite the fact that this file has not changed.  It still seems to upload slightly more than 120MB.

Am I misunderstanding something about how the algorithm works to determine if files have changed or something?

And how does docker build handle wildcards?  i.e.

COPY localdir/* /remotedir/

This is actually a data-only volume.  But I'm not really sure this is the best way to be doing it.  Data only volumes are encouraged but I'm almost thinking uploading the files to a data-only-volume that runs sftp and then uploading the files afterward might be a better approach.  It's a boot server and these are Linux initrd & kernel files.  I don't have many but expect to keep a few around and will remove old ones.

---

Update:
I think I may have uncovered a bug related to the way docker build calculates file changes.  See my github issue [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12421).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docker documentation](http://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/) states:

> In the case of the ADD and COPY instructions, the contents of the
>   file(s) being put into the image are examined. Specifically, a
>   checksum is done of the file(s) and then that checksum is used during
>   the cache lookup. If anything has changed in the file(s), including
>   its metadata, then the cache is invalidated.

Even if the file contents didn't change, a change in the file's metadata will cause the cache to invalidate. So I guess that either the permissions or the creation/update date of your file is changing between your docker build runs.

Comment: Does a change in the update date affect the checksum? I was under the impression that things like update/create date and filename should have no effect on the checksum.

Comment: I read this statement too.  The file is not changed at all.  However, docker copies everything before the build to a temp location.  I wonder just when the checksum is calculated?  or as my work colleague commented, I wonder if the checksum is calculated on the server during the push? which is crazy... surely not because then it would submit the whole base image too? or would it?

Comment: I am not sure what happens there. You can do a `docker build` two times in a row, and the COPY statement is not cached at all?

Comment: @Alp - testing the docker build twice.  I'm also able to confirm the large file appears multiple times in different places beneath /var/lib/docker which suggests it's thinking it's different each time.

Comment: @Alp - yes it's pushed again, no changes to the Dockerfile.  But an entirely new image.  Was just thinking, could access time be part of the metadata.  Many people have noatime set on the mount for ext4... maybe an atime breaks it.  I don't seem to have that set.

Comment: I'm going to accept this, but only because I believe it's a bug.  See updated comments and link to github.

Comment: Very interesting, hope you find a solution soon.